# Extrapolation of Intercept Theorem

Tags: geometry

In Figure 1 below ,the intercept theorem (Centre S) tells us that the ratio of CG:DH = SC:SD

prove that this ratio also applies to GP & HQ which are outside the triangle defined by the theorem.

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your statement, as stated, is false. If we assume that $ABCD$ is a half-circle, it is instead true that
$$
GP:HQ=CP:DQ=CG:DH.
$$
Notice first of all that triangles $ABD$, $AQD$ and $BPG$ are similar, whence:
$GP:PB=AQ:DQ$. Triangles $ABC$, $BPC$ and $AHQ$ are also similar, so we have: 
$HQ:AQ=PB:CP$.

By dividing the first equality by the second one, we thus find $GP:HQ=CP:DQ$. The other equality follows from the usual properties of proportions.

Answer (score 0):

The intercept theorem tells us that $\frac{CG}{DH}=\frac{SC}{\color{red}{SH}}$.

Let we consider $E$ as the intersection of $AD$ and $BC$: we have that $S$ is the orthocenter of $ABE$.
Now we may describe any length involved in the given configuration in terms of $\alpha=\widehat{BAD}$, $\beta=\widehat{EBA}$ and $AB=2R$. For instance,
$$ \frac{AD}{BC} = \frac{2R\cos\alpha}{2R\cos\beta}=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}$$
and
$$ \lambda=\frac{GP}{HQ} = \frac{BP\cot\alpha}{AQ\cot\beta} = \frac{BC\cos\beta\cot\alpha}{AD\cos\alpha\cot\beta}=\frac{\cot\alpha}{\cot\beta}.$$
Additionally, $DQ=AD\sin\alpha = 2R\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$ and 
$$HQ=AQ\cot\beta=AD\cos\alpha\cot\beta =2R\cos^2\alpha\cot\beta.$$
In a similar way, $CP=BC\sin\beta=2R\sin\beta\cos\beta$ and $GP=2R\cos^2\beta\cot\alpha$.
It follows that in general
$$ \frac{DH}{CG}\neq \frac{HQ}{GP}. $$

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed out, this is not true. The ratio $CG:DH = SC:SD$ definitely does not follow from the intercept theorem and is generally not true. Actually, the ratio $CG:DH = SC:SD$ combined with the intercept theorem implies that $SC=SG$ and $SD=SH$ which means that $CDHG$ is an isosceles trapezoid and if $CG < DH$ then $GP > HQ$ which means that $CG : DH \neq GP : HQ$. Do you have some extra conditions?  Maybe you meant $CG:DH = SC:SH$?

So $CG : DH = GP:HQ$ is not true in general. However, **it becomes true if $AB$ is a diameter of the circle**. Then $\angle \, ADB = \angle \, ACB = 90^{\circ}$. Draw the line through $C$ and parallel to $AD$ and let it intersect $AB$ at point $A_1$. After that, draw the line through $D$ and parallel to $BC$ and let it intersect $AB$ at point $B_1$. Then the triangles $AB_1D$ and $A_1BC$ are similar and the lines $DQ$ and $CP$ are the corresponding altitudes of these two similar triangles. Since $A_1C$ is parallel to $AD$ and $AD$ is orthogonal to $BD$, it follows that $A_1C$ is orthogonal to $BD$. Therefore $BD$ is an altitude of triangle $A_1BC$ and thus $G$ is the orthocenter of $A_1BC$. Absolutely the same arguments apply to triangle $AB_1D$ leading to the conclusion that $H$ is its orthocenter. Since $A_1BC$ and $AB_1D$ are similar and $CP$ and $DQ$ are corresponding altitudes, one concludes that $CG:DH = GP : HQ$.